# Angular Typescript Generic Class not throw error

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to use a generic class that works on a set of types (using an interface). When i pass my attributes to the component, i need to throw an error if the type was not respected.

Here is the example : https://codesandbox.io/s/m7ryzwyrj

I defined title as a string, but when i passed title as an Array or Number or something else none errors are throws.

> [title]="{title: []}" <--- No Error Type (but must be a string)

Comment: Angular and the language service don't currently support type checks in the template bindings, see e.g. https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/143. Also please note that a [mcve] should be in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's the answer, one day type checks will be supported ?

Comment: I don't know whether that's planned and certainly can't predict whether it will ever get implemented.